# How do I use price more then 999.99 USD for apple in-app purchase items in iTunes connect?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

There are 87 Tiers in iTunes connect for in-app purchase products but there is no option where we can add custom price. I want to add price more then 999.99 USD but there is no Tier available grater then this.

So please someone tell me how to make this possible?

Comment: talk with apple support

Comment: I tried to find out support email for iTunes connect but couldn't find any. Can you provide me some email address or telephone number where i can contact them?

Comment: https://www.apple.com/contact/

Comment: Thank you. i will try there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question for Apple Support.

Comment: If everyone needs to go to the specific support site, then what is the use of thousands of brilliant developers here. You are voting down this question not because its belongs to apple but you wants to earn some points.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this with **in-app purchase**. You have to select one **tier** from from available tiers. You can communicate apple support if they can do something for you.

Or you can use other payment gateway instead of **in-app purchase**.

Comment: But apple review team is not letting us to use payment gateway other then in-app purchase as we are selling in-tengible or virtual goods.

Comment: then you haven't any option rather than `in-app purchase`. You should try to contact `Apple Support`

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot customize prices or use external services like paypal if you are selling virtual goods.

You need to modify your code to accept more $ from your users

1. Do a **Consumable product** against your existing **non-Consumable** product and you can charge users based on features within your app?
2. Create a **Auto-Renewable** Subscription to charge user Time basis to get more $

Which option to select is based on your app business flow. On Google Play Store max amount varies based on country of selection ( it's 400$ for USA ). Apple allows more 999$